# How to return error message from ajax post in Node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I am submitting a form to node js server via ajax and expect an error if any, but instead of showing me the error , i am redirected to a whole new page with the error. I have used res.send , res.json, res.writheHead()... But i am always redirect to a new page

```
            $.ajax({
                url: $this.attr('/api/adduser'),
                type: $this.attr('POST'),
                data: $this.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json', // JSON
                success: function(json) {
                     alert('Erreur : '+ json.reponse);
                    }
                })
            event.preventDefault()
```

and on the server side i have:

```
    sql.query("INSERT into internes(email,nom,prenom,password,privilege,datenaissance,gender,details,user_Add_Mail)"+
            " VALUES(lower($1),lower($2),lower($3),lower($4),lower($5),$6,$7,lower($8),lower($9))",
            req.body.email,req.body.nom,req.body.prenom,req.body.pass1,priv,req.body.datenaissance,parseInt('0'),req.body.details,req.body.passAdmin)
            .then(function(result){
                res.redirect('/api/users');
            })
            .catch(function(erreur){
                res.json(400, {'success': erreur})
            })
```

Comment: `res.status(400).json({err:"custom"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error you're getting is being identified as a successful response from your sql promise. To fix that do something like

```
sql.query("INSERT into internes(email,nom,prenom,password,privilege,datenaissance,gender,details,user_Add_Mail)"+
        " VALUES(lower($1),lower($2),lower($3),lower($4),lower($5),$6,$7,lower($8),lower($9))",
        req.body.email,req.body.nom,req.body.prenom,req.body.pass1,priv,req.body.datenaissance,parseInt('0'),req.body.details,req.body.passAdmin)
        .then(function(result){
           // look into your result to see if you have what you asked for
           if(result.error) {
                res.status(500).send({error: 'you have an error'}); 
           }
           res.redirect('/api/users');
        })
        .catch(function(erreur){
            res.json(400, {'success': erreur})
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use ajax error:

```
success: function (json) {
    alert(json);
},
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    alert(msg);
}
```

[Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)